# How to show that $f(x,y)$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have been given the function $f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{x^3y-xy^3}{x^2+y^2}, \quad \quad (x,y)\neq 0 ; \\ 0  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad  (x,y)=0.\end{cases}$.

Is it enough to compute all partial derivates and then showing that they are continuous?

Comment: Yes, if the partial derivatives are continuous then $f$ is continuously differentiable.

Comment: For both $(x,y)\neq 0$ and $(x,y)=0$?

Comment: Yes, you have to prove continuity of partial derivatives at all points including $(0,0)$.

Comment: Ok, I showed that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$, so I am good to go to differentiate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it should be enough to compute all partial derivates and then showing that they are continuous. But notice the following:

Your $f$ is two times partial differentiable, but

$\partial_2\partial_1f(0,0)=-1\neq 1=\partial_1\partial_2f(0,0)$

hence (according to Schwarz's theorem) your partial differentials $\partial_1\partial_2f$ or rather $\partial_2\partial_1 f$ can not be continuous.